# awk partial match to append text to file

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to `cp` and `paste` or update each matching line in `f2` to `$3` in `f1` if `$2` of `f1` is in the line in `f2` somewhere. There will always be a match (usually more then 1) and my actual data is much larger (several hundreds of lines) in both `f1` and `f2`. When the line in `f2` is pasted to `$3` in `f1`, the value in `$1` of `f1` is appended to it at the end of the line with a `/test/id/$1_raw.file_fixed.txt`. The `$1` value is from `f1` as well. Most of this is static text, except the value from `$1` is after the third `/`. The lines that begin with `R_2019` are just printed as is and not used to look for a match. The `awk` does execute but the output is unchanged. Thank you :).

I also tried another `awk` (attempt 2) with no luck. I can see that the string in `f2` is being read into `$id` but I can not find the partial match from `f1`. Thank you :).

**f1**

```
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

**f2**

```
/path/to/the/xxx/data/0000-yyyy_v1_0000-yyyy_RNA_v1/190326-Control_v1_20190328071906449 
/path/to/the/xxx/data/00-0000_xxxx-03_v1/00-0000_xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953
/path/to/the/xxx/data/1111-xxxx-03_v1/1111-xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953
```

**desired**

```
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy /path/to/the/xxx/data/0000-yyyy_v1_0000-yyyy_RNA_v1/190326-Control_v1_20190328071906449/test/id/xyxy_0268_raw.file_fixed.txt
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx /path/to/the/xxx/data/1111-xxxx-03_v1/1111-xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953/test/id/xyxy_0270_raw.file_fixed.txt
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) id[$i]=$1; next} $2 in id{$3=id[$i] "/test/id/" $1 "_raw.file_fixed.txt"}1' f2 f1

awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) id[$i]=$1; next} $2 in id{$3=id/$2/ "/test/id/" $1 "_raw.file_fixed.txt"}1' f2 f1
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen if, as you say, there is more than one match?

Comment: There may be multiple matches between the two files, but only one per line. Each match  in `f1` will be unique to one line in `f2` and the matching lines in `f2` are combined with `f1` . Thank you :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$2 in id` won't do what you expect, you need to check each key of the array in a loop using `index`.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} NF>1{for(b in a){if(index(b,$2)){$3=b;delete a[b]}}} 1' f2 f1
xyxy_0268 0000-yyyy /path/to/the/xxx/data/0000-yyyy_v1_0000-yyyy_RNA_v1/190326-Control_v1_20190328071906449 
xyxy_0270 1111-xxxx /path/to/the/xxx/data/1111-xxxx-03_v1/1111-xxxx-03_v1_20190322115521953
R_0000_00_02_00_45_32_xxxx_x0-0000-100-x0.0_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(this code was written as per samples shown only).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {flag="";for(i in a){match(i,$2);if(substr(i,RSTART,RLENGTH)){flag=1;print $0,i}}} !flag' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Comment: @justaguy, could you please try above once and let me know if this helps?

Comment: this works, but what if $2 contains special characters like `?*+`?

Comment: @oguzismail, code was written as per samples given, sorry but didn't assume anything from my side, if you want, please feel free to edit my solution with comments(we will learn from it too), thank you.

Comment: @oguzismail, I became less active these days(lot of work), I always give detailed manner explanation, will try to add here too(if not sleeping in next few mins), thanks and cheers buddy.